# CSS3 Animations & Hover - Working Together?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to make hover effect the element
Here is my code piece and a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Fbk9t/

```
/* Setting up the "myAnim1" for all browser types
-------------------------------------------------*/
 @keyframes myAnim1 {
    0% {
        background-color: #212121;
    }
    50% {
        background-color: #31f4dc;
    }
    100% {
        background-color: #212121;
    }
}
/* Firefox */
 @-moz-keyframes myAnim1 {
    0% {
        background-color: #212121;
    }
    50% {
        background-color: #31f4dc;
    }
    100% {
        background-color: #212121;
    }
}
/* Safari and Chrome */
 @-webkit-keyframes myAnim1 {
    0% {
        background-color: #212121;
    }
    50% {
        background-color: #31f4dc;
    }
    100% {
        background-color: #212121;
    }
}
/* Opera */
 @-o-keyframes myAnim1 {
    0% {
        background-color: #212121;
    }
    50% {
        background-color: #31f4dc;
    }
    100% {
        background-color: #212121;
    }
}
/* Attaching the animations to the elements
Notice the difference between timing!!
-------------------------------------------------*/
 .firstelement {
    display:inline-block;
    animation:myAnim1 5s;
    -moz-animation:myAnim1 5s infinite;
    -webkit-animation:myAnim1 5s infinite;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: 0.3s ease;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}
 .firstelement:hover {
    background-color: #ff0000;}
```

So simply the animation keeps running no matter how I set my hover. hat is the correct route to solve a situation like this?

Notice the transition also..

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop the animation loop when you `:hover` your element, so:

```
 .firstelement:hover {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    animation: none;
    -moz-animation: none;
    -webkit-animation: none;
}
```

here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/Fbk9t/1/

I hope it helps you ;)

Comment: Thank you, I've tried this as well. However, when the animation is removed, the button color gets back to the original state (initial color without the animation) so that the transition no longer continues from where we left the background color..

Answer (score 1):

Change the following code from infinite to 1:

```
Old version:
    -moz-animation:myAnim1 5s infinite;
    -webkit-animation:myAnim1 5s infinite;
New version
    -moz-animation:myAnim1 5s 1;
    -webkit-animation:myAnim1 5s 1;
```

Comment: In that case I suggest a small jQuery code: $('').hover(function() { $(this).addElement('active'); } This will add a.active class and just place the keyframes you had before on the active class :p just comment if you want me to place a fiddle example

Comment: I'd love to see a fiddle!
Thank you!